Nodemailer in Google Cloud Function - spontaneous connection timeout
I'm using Nodemailer inside a google cloud function when new data is added to the database. For sending the e-mail I'm using the SMTP from my own domain and it works in approx. 98% of the cases. The problem is that sometimes I receive a "connection timeout" error and I'm not sure how should I deal with it.
Error: Connection timeout
    at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:130:19)
    at Object.error (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:116:11)
    at /workspace/newTrip/newTripNodemailerV2.js:40:33
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'MAIL.MYDOMAIN.COM',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'user@mydomain.com', // domain email address
      pass: 'userpassword' // my password
    }
  });


Add more information about connections that fail. Remote systems might be down, there is no guarantee about anything in networking. Design for failure and retry later.

Try to increase timeout  to 60 seconds
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'MAIL.MYDOMAIN.COM',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'user@mydomain.com',
    pass: 'userpassword'
  },
  connectionTimeout: 60000 // Increase to 60 seconds
});


This is almost always the wrong answer and can be expensive for serverless applications.
